# How can I update component whenever typing in input tag in React?

Tags: reactjs

What the below code does is to get data from API, and then render it on the page. `searchChange` function takes a value from the input tag, and setValue for `query` state. My api endpoint takes argument to filter the API such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/deals/?q=${query}`.

I'm very confused how I can update the `DealList` component with the API updated with `query` state whenever typing something in the input tag. I'm thinking of that I need to something in `searchChange` function, but not sure what to do there.

**index.js**

```
const useFetch = (url, query, defaultResponse) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(defaultResponse);

  const getDataFromAPI = async url => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(url);

      setResult({
        isLoading: false,
        data
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query.length > 0) {
      getDataFromAPI(`${url}?q=${query}`);
    } else {
      getDataFromAPI(url);
    }
  }, []);

  return result;
};

const Index = ({ data }) => {
  const query = useInput("");

  const apiEndpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/deals/";

  const dealFetchResponse = useFetch(apiEndpoint, query, {
    isLoading: true,
    data: null
  });

  const searchChange = e => {
    query.onChange(e);
    query.setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head title="Home" />
      <Navigation />

      <Container>
        <Headline>
          <h1>The best lease deal finder</h1>
          <h4>See all the lease deals here</h4>
        </Headline>

        <InputContainer>
          <input value={query.value} onChange={searchChange} />
        </InputContainer>

        {!dealFetchResponse.data || dealFetchResponse.isLoading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <DealList dealList={dealFetchResponse.data.data.results} />
        )}
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest challenge in something like this is detecting when a user has stopped typing.. If someone is searching for 'Milk' - when do you actually fire off the API request? How do you know they aren't searching for 'Milk Duds'? (This is hypothetical, and to demonstrate the 'hard' part in search bars/APIs due to their async nature)..

This is typically solved by debouncing, which has been proven to work, but is not very solid.

In this example, you can search Github repos...but even in this example, there are unnecessary requests being sent - this is simply to be used as a demonstration. This example will need some fine tuning..

```js
const GithubSearcher = () => {
  const [repos, setRepos] = React.useState();

  const getGithubRepo = q => {
    fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + q)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        let formattedJson = json.items.map(itm => {
          return itm.name;
        })
        setRepos(formattedJson);
      });
  }

  const handleOnChange = event => {
    let qry = event.target.value;
    if(qry) { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        getGithubRepo(qry);
      }, 500);
    } else {
      setRepos("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Search Github</p>
      <input onChange={event => handleOnChange(event)} type="text" />
      <pre>
        {repos ? "Repo Names:" + JSON.stringify(repos, null, 2) : ""}
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<GithubSearcher />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```